# Give a matrix function and a specific eigenvalue, how to calculate the eigenvector?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Just wondering if someone can help me solve this problem, or point me to some articles on the subject.

I have a function F that corresponds to a large N by N matrix, N is a very large number so the matrix itself cannot be written down. For an eigenvalue E, is there an efficient method for finding the corresponding eigenvectors $\vec{x}$?

$F\vec{x} = E\vec{x}$

The known conditions are:

1. The matrix is its own's inverse, $ F F \vec{x} = \vec{x}$,
2. the function can be called to operate on any vectors,
3. $E = 1$,
4. the are 3 solutions, one of there is known. Just need to find the other two.

Comment: What do you mean by “the solution is degenerate”?

Comment: By degenerate I meant there are more than one solutions. In fact there are 3 solutions in this case, one is known. I need to figure out the other two.

Comment: So your question is actually about finding the eigenspace $E_1$ and not about finding an eigenvector?

Comment: That's right, also find one of the other two eigenvectors will solve my problem.

Comment: I don’t know a good way. First you need to guess a vector which is not a $-1$ eigenvector and then you can use that to get a $1$ eigenvector. You then need to repeat until you get a different $1$ eigenvector which is not colinear to the one you already have. Once you have more than one you can just repeat but replace “colunear to” with “in the span of”

Comment: I thought your answer means for any $x$, whether it is a solution or not, $x + F(x)$ is a solution? I must understood it incorrectly.

Comment: $F(x+Fx) = Fx + FFx = Fx+x=x+Fx$ but you may have $x+Fx=0$ in which case that wouldn’t be a useful eigenvector. Indeed you should find a space of dimension $N-3$ to be annihilated by the linear map $x\mapsto x+Fx$.

Answer (score 2):

You think for a little bit and you realise that:

- as the $F$ is invertable it must have a nullity of 0
- the only possible eigenvalues of $F$ are $1$ and $-1$

So you can decompose $\Bbb R^N$ into the two eigenspaces of $F$ so for some $x$ you get:

$$Fx = F(v+w) = v - w,$$
where $x=v+w$, $Fv=v$ and $Fw = -w$. Thus:

$$x + Fx = v + w + v - w = 2v$$

is an eigenvector of $F$ with eigenvalue 1.

If you repeat this for a basis of $N$ vectors, you should get eigenvector a which span the eigenspace.

Comment: Great answer, this solved the problem I asked.